# Dynamic form variables for post meta

Tags: php, posts, admin, forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form in the wordpress admin where I can add a line and still be able to process the variables into the database as post meta.  I've done quite a bit of research and have tried several methods but cant seem to get it work.     I have a sample of my code here to show how I am processing the info, I just need to figure out how to loop through the dynamic content and then properly update or delete it as necessary.

```
    <?php 

    // Set Up Meta Boxes

    function add_invoice_meta_boxes() {
        add_meta_box('invoice_meta_box', 'Invoice Summary', 'setup_invoice_meta_box', 'invoice', 'normal', 'high');
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_invoice_meta_boxes');

    // Invoice Meta Box
    function setup_invoice_meta_box($post) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="invoice_meta_box_nonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce('invoice_meta_box'). '" />';

    ?>

    <script language="javascript">function addRow(tableID){var table=document.getElementById(tableID);var rowCount=table.rows.length;var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);var colCount=table.rows[0].cells.length;for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){var newcell=row.insertCell(i);newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type){case"text":newcell.childNodes[0].value="";break;case"checkbox":newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;break;case"select-one":newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex=0;break;}}}
    function deleteRow(tableID){try{var table=document.getElementById(tableID);var rowCount=table.rows.length;for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){var row=table.rows[i];var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked){if(rowCount<=1){alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");break;}
    table.deleteRow(i);rowCount--;i--;}}}catch(e){alert(e);}}</script>

    <?php } ?>

    <div class="wrap">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th width="20px">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="202px">Product</th>
        <th width="252px">Description</th>
        <th width="52px">QTY</th>
        <th width="102px">Price</th>
        <th width="102px">Tax</th>
        <th width="202px">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <table id="dataTable">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="gho-chk" name="chk"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="gho-description" name="product[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'product[]', true); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="gho-description" name="description[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'description[]', true); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="gho-qty" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'qty[]', true); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="gho-price" name="price[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'price[]', true); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="gho-tax" name="tax[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'tax[]', true); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="gho-amount" name="amount[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'amount[]', true); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>

    <?php 
    function save_invoice_meta_box($post_id) {
        // check nonce
        if (!isset($_POST['invoice_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['invoice_meta_box_nonce'], 'invoice_meta_box')) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // check capabilities
        if ('invoice' == $_POST['post_type']) {
            if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // exit on autosave
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['product'])) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'product', $_POST['product']);
        } else {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'product');
        }

    }

    add_action('save_post', 'save_invoice_meta_box');

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this working! here is an example of how to set up the form.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.metabox_submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#publish').click();
  });
  $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
      var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
      row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
      row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
      return false;
  });
  $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parents('tr').remove();
      return false;
  });
  $('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody').sortable({
      opacity: 0.6,
      revert: true,
      cursor: 'move',
      handle: '.sort'
  });
  });
  </script>

  <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" class="billing-form">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="bit-5"></th>
          <th class="bit-10">SKU</th>
          <th class="bit-40">Item</th>
          <th class="bit-10">Quantity</th>
          <th class="bit-10">Price</th>
          <th class="bit-16">Total</th>
          <th class="bit-2"></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  if ( $repeatable_fields ) :
      foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) {
  ?>
  <tr>
      <td class="bit-5"><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_sku[]" value="<?php if($field['order_sku'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['order_sku'] ); ?>" /></td>
      <td class="bit-40"><input type="text" name="order_item[]" value="<?php if($field['order_item'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['order_item'] ); ?>" /></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_qty[]" value="<?php if($field['order_qty'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['order_qty'] ); ?>" /></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_price[]" value="<?php if($field['order_price'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['order_price'] ); ?>" /></td>
      <td class="bit-16"><input type="text" name="order_subtotal[]" value="<?php if($field['order_subtotal'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['order_subtotal'] ); ?>" /></td>
      <td class="bit-2"><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
      }
  else :
      // show a blank one
  ?>
  <tr>
      <td class="bit-5"><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_sku[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-40"><input type="text" name="order_item[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_qty[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_price[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-16"><input type="text" name="order_subtotal[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-2"><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
  <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
      <td class="bit-5"><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_sku[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-40"><input type="text" name="order_item[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_qty[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-10"><input type="text" name="order_price[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-16"><input type="text" name="order_subtotal[]" /></td>
      <td class="bit-2"><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a>
  <input type="submit" class="metabox_submit" value="Save" />
  </p>
```